# cocos2d choose the right pattern

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, cocos2d-iphone

I'm working on a game with finding objects on the screen which has also implemented the parallax effect.
For certain reasons I've added my objects as CCMenuItems to the parallax layers

I'd like to know which will be the best design pattern suitable to me in order to handle my objects;

I've found that are six (maybe more of this but this is what I've found so far)

1. Model-View-Controller
2. Delegation
3. Target action
4. Notifications
5. Block model
6. Managed memory model

Any tutorial for the best one would be great! ;)

Comment: Why do you think you need one of these patterns ?

Comment: @robo: Well, I'll have multiple scenes and for the future addons to the game; Do you think that can be done also withoud any of these without any extra time?

Comment: In order to be able to use any of these patterns in a useful way you need to understand more about them. It would not help if somebody told you do pattern X. you need to understand more first - and then your question would sound different :) Tip: get the book "Head First Design Patterns by O'Reilly"

Comment: @robo: It's also for Cocos2d? Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Its not specifically for cocos2d, but its explained really down to earth in plain english and still correct - not as academic as the original version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer: None of these at this time.

Because a) your question is too broad and not specific enough. and b) this indicates you need more general knowledge about patterns first to be able to use them meaningful. I think if you had this knowledge already you would have put the question differently.

I suggest you read up on patterns and software design more, first.
Book Tip: Head First Design Patterns by O'Reilly.

[http://www.amazon.com/First-Design-Patterns-Elisabeth-Freeman/dp/0596007124/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1328729374&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124)